# What's the meaning of "not far off as good as it gets"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> This is not far off as good as it gets.

What meaning the sentence above could have?

The structure of the usual sentence using 'far off' or 'not far off' is like:

The hotel is not far off (from here). It's natural to be ended after 'is: be verb' but the example sentence above has the aditional and independent phrase which also includes 'subject and verb: it gets'—as good as it gets

The example sentence is idiomatic?

Comment: Have you checked dictionaries for the meanings of 'not far off' and 'as good as it gets'?

Comment: Surely. After "not far off" the sentence could be ended. Also, it's confusing what the "not" negates.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include everything that you do not understand. Have you checked as I asked above?

Comment: It's a reasonable question. Apart from a few fixed expressions ("far off bass/center/target") "not far off" is not usually followed by anything. Where it is, you would normally expect a noun phrase: e.g., "not far off the table." "Not far off as good as it gets" sounds really weird, and I'm not surprised an ELL would have a hard time explaining why.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney - the expression is very understandable in British English, where 'not far off' can mean 'closely approaching', 'nearly' or 'almost' - the bill is not far off £500, the delay will be not far off six months, the pit is not far off 500 metres deep, my son is not far off being a genius.

Comment: I dare say there is a nautical origin - the island is not far off (i.e. near to) the coast of Wales.

Comment: Those sound like noun phrases to me. You're making my point. In any case, I only mean to suggest that downvoting the question is inappropriate.

Comment: The phrase as posted is wrong. Punctuation or something else. For example: **This is not far off and as good as it gets**. If you take stuff off the internet without any references etc, it is very difficult to say. I get tired of trying to guess badly written internet comments.

Comment: @Lambie - `This is not far off as good as it gets` is perfectly normal, if informal, British English. Discussion of 1970s farm tractors: 'a Farmhand or Browns loader with a 4wd converted Ford 7600 c/w a big rear weight would be not far off as good as it gets' - wine review 'A smidgen more length would take it into even higher realms (although, let's be fair, it's not far off as good as it gets)'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't buy it. Sorry.

Comment: @Lambie - are you British? I gave two examples. Here's another: `He said: 'This is not far off as good as it gets'. The Sun (2010)` Collins (Dictionary) Corpus

Comment: if you consider 'as good as it gets' to be an -- OK, casual -- fixed phrase meaning 'impossible to improve', and we have dictionary confirmation of that, then the expression is equivalent to 'not far off perfect' which is extremely common - wine review again - 'Pin-sharp. And goes on and on. Excellent. Indeed not far off perfect'. Or 'ideal' - 'As prep runs go, his Chepstow reappearance was not far off ideal' - Irish Independent horse racing story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**'This is not far off as good as it gets' is perfectly normal informal British English, and means 'this is nearly perfect'.**

'Not far off' can mean 'nearly' or 'almost'.

[Synonyms of 'nearly' (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/synonyms/nearly)

'As good as it gets' can mean 'not very good and unlikely to improve', or 'extremely good, so that nothing is better'. I suspect (because of 'not far off') that the second meaning is intended.

[As good as it gets (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-as-good-as-it-gets)